# How do we solve the ODE $y''= \frac{1}{ \cosh (y')}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve
$$y''= \frac{1}{ \cosh (y')} $$
$y(0)=1, y'(0)=0 $

Can I do it by substituting $ y'=z $, $ y''=z' $

and solving

$$ z'= \frac{1}{ \cosh z}$$
$$ \Leftrightarrow \frac{dz}{dx}= \frac1{ \cosh z } $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow \int \cosh z dz = \int 1 dx $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow \sinh z = x+s $$

how do I proceed here?

Comment: Apply the inverse hyperbolic sine function and integrate both sides.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the substitution $y'=z$ and proceed as follows
$$\sinh z = x+s$$ $$\implies z=\sinh^{-1}(x+s)$$ $$\implies y'=\sinh^{-1}(x+s).$$

Then, $y'(0)=0\implies 0=\sinh^{-1}(s) \implies s=0.$ Therefore $y' =\sinh^{-1}(x)$. Integrating both sides and using the identity

$$\int \sinh^{-1}(ax)\,dx=x\sinh^{-1}(ax)-\frac{\sqrt{a^2x^2+1}}{a}+C,$$

gives

$$y=x\sinh^{-1}(x)-\sqrt{x^2+1}+C.$$

Now evaluate $y(0)=1$ to find $C$.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, since $\sinh$ is invertible, you can just apply its inverse function to both sides yielding $$z = \operatorname{arsinh} (x + s)$$
From there, you can substitute $y$ in, integrate, and apply initial conditions.